# Which semantics is better for a list of articles?

Tags: html, html-lists, outliner

I was asking myself for the markup of a list of entries of a blog.

Which could be like that:

Case 1 :

```
<article>...</article>
<article>...</article>
<article>...</article>
```

or case 2 :

```
 <ol reversed>
    <li><article>...</article></li>
    <li><article>...</article></li>
    <li><article>...</article></li>
 </ol>
```

The example seems to be logic: "it's a list of entries order by desc date"

An other example is a list of important step to use a product:

```
<ol>
     <li><section><h1>step 1</h1></section></li>
     <li><section><h1>step 2</h1></section></li>
     <li><section><h1>step 3</h1></section></li>
</ol>
```

To get an outline like:

```
product name
    description
    how to use
       step 1
       step 2
       step 3
    customer reviews
    etc
```

Do you think it’s too much markup for this content?

My purpose is to get a best HTML5 syntax and outline, but I don’t want to fill the HTML with useless tags.

EDIT: The real question isn’t what is better but it’s more something like to know what developers are thinking about this different ways. Because there are a lot of ways to do things, but sometimes if 2 ways are correct there is maybe a more "logical" or "relevant" method to do it.

Comment: there is no "better" way. if there was a formula for those things, we programmers wouldnt be needed anymore. do whatever u think is best.

Comment: Yes I completely agree with you my question is not very good .... In fact i would like to know what developers think about this different ways... I will edit :)

Answer (score 3):

[`ol`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element) must only be used if "changing the order would change the meaning". Just because content is *sorted* somehow doesn’t necessarily mean that `ol` is appropriate.

If you should use a list (whether `ol` or `ul`) depends on your actual content and its context, it can’t be answered generally. The HTML5 spec defines these lists as "list of items", without specifying what a *list* is or what qualifies as *item*.

A possible/subjective rule of thumb (with many exceptions): Look at your content and ask yourself if you would call it a list, and if you could picture it with typical bullet points.

A page, titled "Blog", showing 10 fulltext blog posts? Probably not.
A sidebar, titled "Related posts", showing 10 links to blog posts? Probably yes.

This suggests that the "complexity" of content might play a role, too, so another possible/subjective rule of thumb (with even more exceptions): If an item has a heading (i.e., it’s a section) and long content, you might not need a list.

Steps to use a product, where each step consists of long explanations with images? Probably not.
Steps to use a product, where each step consists of a short sentence? Probably yes.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with unor.

According to the standard:

> While it is conforming to include heading elements (e.g. h1) inside li elements, it likely does not convey the semantics that the author intended. A heading starts a new section, so a heading in a list implicitly splits the list into spanning multiple sections.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element

So I think if content can have heading - it is not appropriate to include it in the list.