# Should I use div's or ul li tags to Structure my HTML content

Tags: html, semantic-markup

For this example I have six very basic items that all share the same styling and each link to a new separate page. So I was just wondering which of the below code examples is semantically correct or how can I go about making it correct?

I'm hoping to apply this answer to this exact example but I'm also hoping to use the same principles on more complex versions at a later date.

Basically I just want to learn how to properly structure content even if it seems like a huge over kill on some very basic elements?

I'm also using the grid system from here: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/

Thank you for your time!

**Code Example 1 of 2 using div tags**

```
 <section class="group global-width col span_12_of_12">
        <h1>Section Title</h1>

            <div class="col span_2_of_12">
                <h2>
                    <a href="#" title="Example title text">Title One</a>
                </h2>
            </div>

        <div class="col span_2_of_12">
            <h2>
                <a href="#" title="Example title text">Title Two</a>
            </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col span_2_of_12">
            <h2>
                <a href="#" title="Example title text">Title Three</a>
            </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col span_2_of_12">
            <h2>
                <a href="#" title="Example title text">Title four</a>
            </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col span_2_of_12">
            <h2>
                <a href="#" title="Example title text">Title Five</a>
            </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col span_2_of_12">
            <h2>
                <a href="#" title="Example title text">Title Six</a>
            </h2>
        </div>

</section><!-- END OF CODE EXAMPLE ONE -->
```

**Code example 2 of 2 using ul li tags**

```
 <section class="group global-width col span_12_of_12">
        <h1>Section Title</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="col span_2_of_12">
            <h2>
                <a href="#" title="Example title text">Title One</a>
            </h2>
        </li>

        <li class="col span_2_of_12">
            <h2>
                <a href="#" title="Example title text">Title Two</a>
            </h2>
        </li>

        <li class="col span_2_of_12">
            <h2>
                <a href="#" title="Example title text">Title Three</a>
            </h2>
        </li>

        <li class="col span_2_of_12">
            <h2>
                <a href="#" title="Example title text">Title Four</a>
            </h2>
        </li>

        <li class="col span_2_of_12">
            <h2>
                <a href="#" title="Example title text">Title Five</a>
            </h2>
        </li>

        <li class="col span_2_of_12">
            <h2>
                <a href="#" title="Example title text">Title Six</a>
            </h2>
        </li>

        </ul>
</section><!-- END OF CODE EXAMPLE TWO -->
```

Comment: If it's a nav, I would use `li` and get rid of the `h2`s (unless you have further copy under each of them).  If there is going to be further copy below each heading, then I would use a div

Comment: Thank you for you super fast reply. I don't plan for this to be a navigational element and I do hope to place more content in below. Thank you again

Comment: Then I would go with divs (or even sections) - unless the sections are a list, then you have to ask is it un-ordered or ordered.  I guess the main question is, if you took away all styling and the page was presented as plain text, would you be happy that those headings were in a bulleted list

Comment: Yes each piece of content was going to one day turn into a list; for example if i was selling t-shirts i may have, titles, links, images etc for a single product and that would then be repeated for each t-shirt on a single page showing 10+ t-shirts for example. So for the sounds of things I should just stick to divs but is there ever a time you would use ul li for things other than navigation? Thank you!

Comment: Ah if it is for products, you may consider the [article tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article).  As for the uls - I just use them for navs, sitemaps and actual unordered lists.  I have never seen the need to use them on anything else really, but that's just my opinion

Comment: My original idea was that each one of the six divs above was going to link to an individual page that showed a training course of some description. I was then hoping to one day expand each div into more of a product like system that then showed titles, images etc like my t-shirt example. The answer I was hoping to put across was more about the relationship of related items but the more I talk about it the more it sounds just like a list of products. So if i was to use the article tag how would I change my above examples? sorry for sending you around and around. God dam armatures Lol!

Comment: I guess I would just change the `div`s for articles.  It's sometimes easy to overthink these things and there are many ways to do the same thing.  At the end of the day, most of these things are preference and if it makes sense to you to do it, for example, many people argue that you shouldn't use an article tag for products as it is not an "article", but I think that it's okay as it says *any other independent item of content*.  The example in the link above shows good usage of the article tag (with nested articles)

Comment: thank you so much for your time and I shell give that article a read and i'm sure i will have tons of new questions. thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the content; not what it may be in the future, but what it currently is.

If each item consists only of a link, don’t use a heading element (`h2`). A heading opens a new section, but there is no point in having a section if it contains no other content. Using a list probably makes sense here, assuming that the 6 items are in some kind of relationship (which seems to be the case, as they are in the same `section`).

```
<section>
  <h1>Section Title</h1>

  <ul>
    <li>Title One</li>
    <li>Title Two</li>
    <li>Title Three</li>
  </ul>

</section>
```

If an item contains more content, like a description or an image (i.e., it becomes a teaser), you might want to use a sectioning content element. The `article` element is typically appropriate here (e.g., for products, blog posts, etc.). Using a list [in addition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30846292/1591669) is possible, but, I think, not so common; [I wouldn’t recommend it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27699780/1591669), unless you need an ordered list (e.g., [for conveying the ranking in case each item is a search result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11970336/1591669)).

```
<section>
  <h1>Section Title</h1>

  <article>
    <h2>Title One</h2>
    <!-- more content -->
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Title Two</h2>
    <!-- more content -->
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Title Three</h2>
    <!-- more content -->
  </article>

</section>
```

This structure cannot only be used for teasers, but even for "full content" items.

Comment: Thank you for your reply unor. It helps backup Pete's argument about using the article tag which is very reassuring.  Also, thank you for the way you explained the two above examples, they were very simple and easy to understand. Hats off to both you and Pete for your help in making us armatures one step closer to being better coders.  :)