# Should a <ul><li> list always look like a list for it to be semantically correct?

Tags: html, seo, html-lists, semantic-markup

I like to do my post layouts in the context of a blog like this:

```
<ul class="layout1">
    <li class="post">..</li>
    <li class="post">..</li>
    ..
</ul>
```

Which pans out to something like:

[image: The Layout]

This allows me to, in my brain say "Okay, this is a LIST OF posts", **it just doesn't look like a vertical list:**

[image: The Classic List View]

Concretely, is this an issue in terms of (1) performance and (2) SEO?

Comment: How it appears visually has nothing to do with semantically correct code. Simply read the specifications for lists and list items and follow the rules.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about SEO, so maybe this should be moved to Webmasters stack exchange.

Comment: Note that asking for SEO advice is off-topic here; on-topic is to ask about whether the use is valid/semantic. For the latter, see also: [Which semantics is better for a list of articles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22684408/1591669) · [Should I use 'li' or 'article' for products listing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30844508/1591669)

Answer (score 0):

No, you're fine. This wouldn't be an issue for SEO or performance.